# Does the mean value theorem hold for differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know the mean value theorem for differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I was just wondering if someone could tell me if the statement still holds for differentiable functions  from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Depends on which form of the mean value theorem you refer to. $\lvert f(y) - f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert y-x\rVert \cdot \max \{ \lVert Df((1-t)x + ty)\rVert : t \in [0,1]\}$ holds.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does the proof go basically the same as the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case?

Comment: Yes. It's essentially the same proof for all normed spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Think about
$$
f(x)=e^{ix}.
$$
Note that
$$
f(2\pi)-f(0)=0
$$
but $|f'(x)|=1$ for all $x\in{\bf R}$.